# create groups and add object from input file

Tags: arrays, perl

I am a novice to perl programming and keen to learn it,
I am in need of extraction of some data from below sample file. The content of file "test.txt" is multiple groups and objects, but added per line.

set group address Group1 add XYZ1
set group address Group1 add XYZ2
set group address Group2 add XYZ1
set group address Group2 add XYZ4
set group address Group2 add XYZ4
set group address Group3 add XYZ5

I need to convert the above to lines,

Group-name Group1 add members XYZ1, XYZ2
Group-name Group2 add members XYZ1, XYZ4, XYZ5
Group-name Group1 add members XYZ4, XYZ5

for me the logic could be 
1. loop to read each line in an array,
2. store group name and filed in a variables
3. compare group variables, if same concatenate field variables.

If someone can correct the logic and assist me, would be really helpful.
Appreciating in advance.

Regards,

Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Perl and you hear something like "unique" or "grouping" - very likely it's a job for a hash table aka associative array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
while (<>) {
     # .... extract key & value from your data
     $hash{$unique_key} .= " ".$added_value;
}
# ...

foreach (keys %hash) {
    do_something( $_, $hash{$_} );
    # this will be the key and all the 
    # corresponding values combined.
};
```